# php openssl sign file

Tags: php, cryptography, openssl, php-openssl

I want to create a signature with openssl. I have an executable command like the following, but I don't know how to translate it to PHP.

```
openssl cms -sign -inkey key.pem -signer signature.pem -outform DER -in xy.xml
```

How to call this command in PHP?

Comment: We are not a translation service.

Answer (score 2):

```
exec('openssl cms -sign -inkey key.pem -signer signature.pem -outform DER -in xy.xml')
```

With this command you make php call the *openssl* command of the operating system, like you do when you write it on a terminal.

If you want to do it in a native way (php functions) you can take a look at the OpenSSL library  http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php and the function sign http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are (sometimes) good enough, but Code+explanation answers are always better

Comment: I was looking through the OpenSSL library, but I couldn't figure out how to execute the function with the preferred parameters in PHP. Therefore I asked the question. Because the sign function do not provide the used parameters and the pkcs7 function has restrictions. So I will use the shell_exec function anyway.

Answer (score -2):

```
openssl_cms_sign('xy.xml', "xy.xml.sign", file_get_contents('signature.pem'), file_get_contents('key.pem'), null, 0, OPENSSL_ENCODING_DER)
```

Comment: Please add supporting info to your answer to improve it.